# vs code/python interpreter - problem with working with current script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to start the interpreter in vs code, and I want my script to be loaded, so that I can experiment with it, like in python IDLE.

I tried using REPL, on the terminal it shows "c:\currentWorkingDir> & ~.../Python3.10.exe", it starts the interpreter, but the script is not loaded.

Another way, if I manually type in the terminal "python -t script.py" the interpreter loads the script, but if in it, there is prompt for input and I decide to stop it (crtl^c), it throws me out of interpreter back to c:.

Is there a way to load current code in the interpreter and if, force-stopped, to stay loaded, so I can do stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal "python -i script_name.py" is working.